# Grunt source file relative path

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

Why must the leading slash be removed in the source file paths in order for Grunt to properly locate the files? The gruntfile is in the main project older along with the "includes" folder that contains the JS files.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var SiteMasterHeaderArray = [
        "/includes/js/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js",
        "/includes/js/common/common.js" 
    ];

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        uglify: {
            dest: {
                files: {
                    'dest/SiteMasterHeader.js': SiteMasterHeaderArray
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

The destination file isn't written because (at least it appears this way to me) that Grunt is searching some other location for these files due to the "/" in the file path. Remove the slash and the function works perfectly.

Comment: If a file path starts with '/' it's an absolute path. http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/

Comment: Perfect, that explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A leading `/` means it's an **absolute** path and it's looking for it, starting from the root directory. Without that, it's searching for a **relative** path from where `Gruntfile.js` is.

If you'd like paths to be relative to a different folder than `Gruntfile`, please see `grunt.file.setBase` or the `--base` cli option. [More information here](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.setbase).